# Converting a curl to python requests

Tags: curl, python-requests, artifactory

I want to convert my folowing CURL request to a python POST requests 
so I can use it with the requests library

```
curl -uadmin:AP31vzchw5mYTkB1u3DhjLT9Txj -T <PATH_TO_FILE> "http://MyArtifactory-Server/artifactory/OurRepo/<TARGET_FILE_PATH>"
```

Can anyone help in this case ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two aspects involved in your case is [authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/) and [file uploading](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file), you can refer to the links for more details. And also with the converted code below if you want it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


def upload_file():
    username = 'admin'
    password = 'AP31vzchw5mYTkB1u3DhjLT9Txj'
    source_file = "<your source file"
    upload_url = "http://<your server>/<your path>"

    files = {'file': open(source_file, 'rb')}
    requests.post(upload_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), files=files)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    upload_file()
```

Hope this helps:-)

Answer (score 46):

You have this utility:

https://curlconverter.com

I use it all the time. An example is attached. [image]

Comment: You just made my day :)

Comment: @Orsiris de Jong : happy to help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[@MouIdri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49402534/19907524) links [a site](https://curl.trillworks.com/) that doesn't work for me. I found [this](https://curlconverter.com/)

which converted a curl command:

```
curl -uadmin:AP31vzchw5mYTkB1u3DhjLT9Txj -T "<PATH_TO_FILE>" "http://MyArtifactory-Server/artifactory/OurRepo/<TARGET_FILE_PATH>"
```

to python code:

```py
import requests

with open('<PATH_TO_FILE>', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

response = requests.put(
    'http://MyArtifactory-Server/artifactory/OurRepo/<TARGET_FILE_PATH>',
    data=data,
    auth=('admin', 'AP31vzchw5mYTkB1u3DhjLT9Txj'),
)
```

my actual code is different but that's the OP's curl (so not tested)